# How Functional components are working without essential render function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

While going through the docs find that render function is a essential life cycle method. In the case of functional components ,there is no render function.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes when using class components componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount(), render() are essential life cycle methods. In react functional components there is the useEffect Hook and in your case the:

```
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    <div/>
);
```

to replace the render function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. In functional components, there is no need for a render function.

A functional component is just a plain JavaScript function that returns JSX. A class component is a JavaScript class that extends React.Component which has a render method. When defining a class component, you have to make a class that extends React.Component. The JSX to render will be returned inside the render method.

Source: https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components